# Should &nbsp; not be rendered with the same width as a space?

Tags: html, letter-spacing

When I open the following little html document in Firefox (Arch Linux) it is rendered like so:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
<style>
/* * { font-family: Noto Sans UI          } */
/* * { font-family: DejaVu Serif          } */
/* * { font-family: Bitstream Vera Sans   } */
   * { font-family: Bitstream Vera Serif  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

   Foo&nbsp;Bar<br>
   Foo Bar

</body>
</html>
```

I believe this had not always been the case and I thought that `&nbsp;` should be rendered with the same with as an "ordinary" space. Apparently, this is not the case. So, how can I create a non breaking space with the same width as a space?

**Edit** Apparently, this is the case when I use *Bitstream Vera Sans* or *Serif*. When I use *Noto Sans UI* or *DejaVu Serif* both spaces are rendered with the same with.

Comment: Is it the same behavior if you use a different font?

Comment: @Dave, it turns out, it's only(?) the case with Bitstream Vera.

Comment: Yes they should. Also, fonts with whitespaces should be quoted. But I guess that does not have any influence on this issue.